# Does Wviz works on Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) with ROS Electric version

Tags: ros, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I downloaded the wviz package but i get a lot of trouble during the compilation.
It's looking for some packages that do not exist (move_arm_msgs,mapping_msgs,planning_environment_msgs ...)
Moreover i have some issue with some library ros independant like ompl.
However, ros-fuerte-ompl Version 0.10.2001850-0oneiric-20120413-1454-+0000 is installed on my computer.

Hope you can help,

Thanks,

Benoit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32391/does-wviz-works-on-ubuntu-11.10-(oneiric)-with-ros-electric-version/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-23**:
Please state how you installed it and how to reproduce your errors.  And exactly what your errors are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you stick to one ROS version during your installation and use. You mention you try to get it working on ROS electric, but also say you installed some Fuerte packages. They can happily live side by side, but your environment setup should only use one version:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

As for the missing packages, it looks like you didn't search that well ;):

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment_msgs
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm_msgs
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/mapping_msgs
- http://ros.org/wiki/octomap
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/collision_environment_msgs

where the octomap_msgs is the only one not having a dedicated page - but I suspect the package to be available in the octomap_mapping stack.

In case you are new to ROS, you might want to try some tutorials to familiarize yourself:

http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-04-25**:
octomap_msgs is indeed a new stack and not indexed yet. It's released as .deb though, and available from http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/octomap_mapping-fuerte/ for Fuerte.